# What are the issues with enabling Cross Site in OrientDB

Tags: cross-domain, orientdb

I'm using OrientDB as my first database of choice for my project.
My database is hosted on a different server than my website.
I'm accessing the database over http and there's a big warning about this on the OrientDB website here:  http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Web-Server.html

By enabling Cross Site, am I opening myself up to some security issues down the road?

Answer (score 0):

You can secure `HTTP` and binary protocols using `SSL`, for more information see [official documentation about SSL in OrientDB](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Using-SSL-with-OrientDB.html).

Other security tips can be found [here](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Server-Security.html).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Usually is not a good idea opening the database directly to the Internet, for at least the following reasons:

- You should double check all the authorizations to avoid exposing data to everybody
- The OrientDB server is not evolved like Apache with all the anti spoof/dos/attach mechanisms modern web servers have